# in webpack, force some modules to be automatically loaded at startup

Tags: webpack

In my server-side bundle, I have some modules that contains server-side api and I would like to make these modules to be loaded (and run) as soon as possible (at the same time as the entry point).

I have some constraints:

- I don't know the name of these modules (they are generated during the compilation and they are just "marked" from a
  loader, using `this._module.meta.myApiModule = true`).
  These modules are partially shared between client and server in an isomorphic web app. The client knows the server module hash because client-side and server-side module share the same hash (thanks to `webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin`). In some situations, the client make api calls to the server, and the module that holds the api must be loaded before the call.
- all marked modules must be called (required) at startup.
  These modules contains code to register their api (eg. `mainFramowork.registerRpcApi(...)`) this is why they must be loaded at startup.

### more details:

I use vuejs and my .vue files are processed by webpack. Each vue file generates webpack modules (for the script part, the markup part, style, and optionally customBlocks that can be used freely)

```
foo.vue (file)
-> html (webpack module)
-> script (webpack module)
-> style (webpack module)
-> customBlock (webpack module, rawRequest:"!!babel-loader!addmeta-loader?{"mark":"api"}!XXX/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=customBlocks&index=1!./foo.vue")

bar.vue
-> html (webpack module)
-> script (webpack module)
-> style (webpack module)
-> customBlock (webpack module, rawRequest:"!!babel-loader!addmeta-loader?{"mark":"api"}!XXX/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=customBlocks&index=1!./bar.vue")
```

Now, my aim is to call ALL these "customBlock modules":

- at startup (how??) **OR**
- on chunk load (maybe with an entry point in the
  chunk??, this implies to move all my customBlocks modules in a new
  chunk then dynamically create a module that will call all my
  customBlock modules (wow)) **OR**
- by hand: `require('please_call_all_custom_blocks_modules_thanks')` **OR**
- using a loader: `require('please_call_all_custom_blocks_modules_thanks!')`

I don't know

Comment: Could you clarify that not knowing the modules name part?

Comment: I added more details about modules name

Comment: I found this plugin: https://github.com/nezed/webpack-split-chunks maybe it will help me...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this

```
// loader.js
var moduleName = getSomeModuleNameInRuntime();
require("bundle!./path/" + moduleName)(function(myModule) {
  // ...
});
```

see this issue [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1421)

Comment: unfortunately the moduleName is only known after the compilation. Furthermore I only have the request of the module (because the module is generated during the compilation)

Comment: do you know to which directory the generated modules will go in general?

Comment: no directory, they are generated as webpack modules